# Is $(n+\ell)^{-1}\binom{kn}{n}$ an integer for only $(\ell,k)=(1,2)$?

Tags: number-theory, binomial-coefficients

> Find all pairs $(\ell,k)$ of natural numbers, such that the number $\dfrac1{n+\ell}\dbinom{kn}{n}$ is an integer for all natural $n$.

Is $(\ell,k)=(1,2)$ the only solution?

Comment: When $k=2$ this is problem $4$ of China MO 2015.

Comment: Can you provide a link?

Comment: In fact it's stronger. http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?p=3686197&sid=d11e21c8830e27b3fa339ee1a0399abb#p3686197

Comment: @JorgeFernández Unless I misread the problem (or its translation), the question isn't *exactly* the same: it just asks to find $l$ so that the quotient is an integer for infinitely many $n$, not all.

Comment: No, it asks to find $l$ so that there are infinitely values that the quotient is NOT an integer.

Comment: @JorgeFernández Sorry, you're right. But it's still not quite the same question.

Comment: No,  it is stronger, if you prove there are infinite there is at least one. This question seems easier.

Comment: so, is $l=1,k=2$ the only solution?

Comment: I'm close to finishing, give me a sec.

Comment: Ok,I'm not close to finishing.

Comment: But I think even $k$ and $l=1$ always works.

Comment: nevermind, it doessn't

Comment: $l$ must be odd, and $(l+1)\,\mid\,k$. But that's pretty much obvious.

Comment: for example, for which k, l ?

Comment: 8,1 seems to work, I tried it up to $n=100$. In fact I have the conjecture the only counterexamples when $k$ divides $l(l+1)$ occur when $n+l$ is a prime.

Comment: Not for $n=6$; you get $\frac{12271512}{7}$. But that is the only $n$ up to $n=100$ which fails.

Comment: oh, you're right oops, my conjecture doesn't hold with $k=10,n=8$ and $l=1$.

Comment: Oh, I think $k=14,l=1$ does the trick.

Comment: for k =14, l= 1 if n=12 , you get  $\frac{705873715441872264}{13}$

Comment: The case when $l=1$ may be interesting, I'll be back in about 4 hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose there is a solution $(k,\ell)$ with $\ell>1$. Then setting $n=1$ shows that $k$ is a multiple of $\ell+1$. Suppose $p$ is a prime dividing $\ell$; then $k\equiv 1\mod{p}$ as well. Let $n = p$:
$$
  \dbinom{kn}{n} 
    = \frac{kp(kp-1)\cdots(kp-(p-1))}{p!}
     = \frac{k(kp-1)\cdots(kp-(p-1))}{(p-1)!},
$$
which is not divisible by $p$ since $k$ is not. But the denominator is
$$n+\ell = p+\ell \equiv 0\mod{p}.$$
So the only solutions have $\ell=1$ (and $k$ even).

Now suppose that $\dbinom{kn}{n}$ is a multiple of $n+1$ for all natural numbers $n$. If $k>2$, choose $p\,\mid\,k-1$ with $p$ odd, so that $k\equiv 1\mod{p}$. Then set $n=p-1$. By a computation similar to the one above
\begin{align*}
  \dbinom{k(p-1)}{p-1}
    &= \frac{k(p-1)(k(p-1)-1)(\cdots)(k(p-1)-(p-2))}{(p-1)!} \\
    &= \frac{k(p-1)(kp-k-1)\cdots(kp-k-(p-2))}{(p-1)!}.
\end{align*}
But none of 
$$k,\ kp-k-1,\ kp-k-2, \dotsc,\ kp-k-(p-2) \equiv 1,\ -2,\ -3, \dotsc,\ -(p-1) \mod{p}$$ 
is divisible by $p$ since $k\equiv 1\mod{p}$, so the expression is not divisible by $p$. But $n+1 = p-1+1=p$ and the quotient is not an integer.

So $\ell=1$, $k=2$ is the only solution.

Comment: So the only solutions have $\ell=1$ (and $k$ even). What if l=1,k=4?

Comment: Let $n=2$; then $\dbinom{4\cdot 2}{2} = 28$ while $n+1=3$.